# Which python script allow me to know if tor is operational or not as a client?

Tags: python, stem

Which stem python code would you suggest to determine whether tor is operational (bootstrapped at 100%) or not?

Comment: As a client or as a relay?

Comment: As a client, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the client bootstrap status. It's done - as it's said in [control protocol spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) like this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
AUTHENTICATE "cleartextpassword"
250 OK
GETINFO status/bootstrap-phase
250-status/bootstrap-phase=NOTICE BOOTSTRAP PROGRESS=100 TAG=done SUMMARY="Done"
250 OK
QUIT
250 closing connection
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

You need - if using Stem - a [Controller](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller) class, and the python code doing exactly this will be:

```
import stem
import stem.connection
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password = 'cleartextpassword')
    response=controller.get_info("status/bootstrap-phase")
    controller.close()

if(response.find('SUMMARY="Done"') > 0):
    print "bootstrapped OK"
else:
    print "Bootstrap not finished: " + response
```

Have a good day!